# TangoPoseData 'pose.status_code' always remains VALID even if the device steps out of the Area Descrition File

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Tango `pose.status_code` always remains `VALID` after localization even if the device steps out of the ADF.

How do I know if the device has moved out of the ADF?

I have tried with both `AreaLearningMode = enabled` & `Loading Existing ADF`and all combinations of `FramePair`; but in both cases `pose.status_code` is always `VALID` even if we step out of the ADF.

Answer (score 0):

It's intended to have ADF pose status to be `valid` even after device is out of ADF area. Under the hood, ADF pose is just a motion tracking pose with ADF's transformation correction on top of that. Thus even if it's out of the ADF, as long as motion tracking is working fine, it can still produce valid pose.

To check if device is out of an ADF, the easiest way is to listen to `ADF_T_StartOfService` frame. With a healthy/well-constructed ADF, you should be able to see this framepair constantly produce callbacks. Each callback indicates a "frame match". If there's no "frame match" after certain period of time, it's pretty safe to say that either user is out of an ADF or the area is deprecated (visual feature changed)

Other method to check ADF boundary is to save a file with the trajactory of recorded path, there's no built-in feature like this from Tango API. Thus it has to be done from the app level.