# How to read Google Tango area learned tracking success, confidence, accuracy via Tango API?

Tags: google-project-tango

I have a Google Tango application where position repeat accuracy of a learned area description is critical. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMbNykdPDRo

When area description tracking is activated, the repeat accuracy normally is high. However, if finding learned feature points in a learned area description fails after a certain time (e.g. after lighting conditions changed or the device entered a not yet learned area), repeat accuracy decreases (due to starting missing area description).

How could we get some feedback from the area tracking success to detect such as case? 
Examples: how many feature points/frames were successfully tracked against some ADF, or how confident/accurate the pose position actually is for a certain area description?

I cannot find anything useful in the API.

I know such a that field is existing in the Tango Core as you can clearly see in the Tango Debug Overlay App ('Tracking Success').
http://grauonline.de/alexwww/tmp/tango_debug_overlay_app.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The tracking data is not available through API, the tool you saw from the picture is developed by Tango team, and it can be downloaded [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projecttango.experiments.debugoverlay).

On top of API, the best way to identify pose quality is to check pose status returned from callbacks, and check TangoEvent data.

Comment: Thanks. This does not help as the pose status is showing me 'still valid' although I left completely the ADF learned area. What I need is a feedback from the Tango engine that an area (or more important: a part of it) needs to be relearned to be useful for relocalization. How could I do this?  The pose status is not giving any feedback on this.

Comment: There's currently no direct way of detecting if device is within an ADF or not. See my reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141779/tangoposedata-pose-status-code-always-remains-valid-even-if-the-device-steps-out/41559145#41559145

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your suggested monitoring of  'ADF_T_StartOfService' frame pairs. Looking at the trajectory would not help as the trajectory will only tell us the area that was used for the initial ADF learning but will not tell us if part of that area changed (in time) and so is no longer usable for relocalization.

Comment: Monitoring 'ADF_T_StartOfService' does still continue to trigger in areas where the ADF was not learned (or where conditions changed over time like sunlight to room light). However, I was able to get Tango engine debug information as simple text on UDP port 29361 (like Tango Debug Overlay App). I know this is not a final solution (not for release builds), it just works for my prototype here.

Comment: `ADF_T_StartOfService` shouldn't be updating if there's truly no common feature in the scene. Could it be that you walk in a new area, but the new area and old area has common features at a distant location?

Comment: I think that cannot be because Tango Debug Overlay App stops counting 'Tracking Success'. Maybe I misunderstood ADF_T_StartOfService completely? I'm using Java API Tango.connectListener with frame pairs (base=COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION and target=COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE). Is there any Google app to verify this 'feature'? Google Tango Explorer App shows 'Device in respect of Start of Service' as blue line and 'Device in respect to ADF' in green line - both do not stop drawing when Google Tango Debug Overlay 'Tracking Success' stops counting.

Comment: PS: In Tango Core 01-19-2017 the 'Tracking Success' counter does not seem to work anymore.